# What is "app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" used for?

Tags: android, layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

Can anyone please explain what `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` is used for?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-constraint-bias look at this, easy to understand

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Position View - bias

bias: (constraint area size - view size) distribution ratio.

app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0~1"

0: Attach to the left

1: Attach to the right

0.5: Center (default)

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    ... />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
    ... />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default when encountering such opposite constraints is to center the widget; but you can tweak the positioning to favor one side over another using the bias attributes:

layout_constraintHorizontal_bias
layout_constraintVertical_bias

Basically for this type of questions you should check Official Documentation instead of posting here... here is link to official documnetation for Bias....
[Learn More About Bias](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Bias)